# Set random-seed just for the first simulation of a series of repetitions with Behavior Space

Tags: netlogo

I have to test different algorithms with netlogo. I have a different Netlogo model to simulate each algorithm.

I would like to use *Behavior Space* tool to run a series of simulations with every model, and use `random-seed` to replicate the events that occur at random with all the models (algorithms). 
Therefore, I will set a *Behavior Space* Experiment for each method. And in the Experiment settings I will set a number of Repetitions to compute different samples of the results.

The problem is that setting a random-seed, for example in the setup procedure of the models will produce that repetition of events for each Experiment of the Behavior Space, however, it will produce the same results in all the repetitions of the experiment.

What I would need is to run the series of simulations of the model setting the random-seed only in the first simulation, so that the results obtained repeating the simulations of the model with Netlogo (the samples obtained) will be different, and all the Experiments will use the same sequence of random events that I would need to compare the different algorithms.

Is there any way of setting a Behavior Space Experiment with a number of repetitions, and generate the same random sequence in another experiment with the same number of repetitions?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `behaviorspace-run-number`.  E.g., as the simplest example, in the model setup include the line

```
random-seed behaviorspace-run-number
```

Comment: Thank you very much